# How to get rid of React Select Import Error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import

I'm trying to use the select input tool for ReactJS (https://react-select.com/home#getting-started) so I can have a filter/search bar on my website. I copied and pasted the code from the link above into a new file in my src folder. At this point I had no errors, but when I import this filter file into my App.js file and run it, I get the following error:

```
Module not found: You attempted to import ../data which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.
```

Here are the imports for the filter file:

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';
import { colourOptions } from '../data';
import { Note } from '../styled-components';
```

The rest of the code is in the link above (I used the Single search, the first one that comes up). I've looked up several things and can't seem to figure out how to get rid of this error!
[EDIT] I don't even know where this data file is in my project or my computer. I've searched for it and I have a million data files, so I'm unsure of what to bring into my src folder. I'm also having the same problem with the styled-components import. When I search for that on my computer, nothing comes up.

Comment: You data file is outside src folder.... put inside and call it `import { colourOptions } from './data';`

Answer (score 0):

```
import { colourOptions } from '../data';
```

The above import seems to be incorrect. You might have want to import the from the data.js which is in the same directory as of your App.js.

```
import { colourOptions } from './data';
```

This can help you solve the error. Also make sure the data.js file is in the same directory as of App.js.